# Give us the new hotness <kbd> styles

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

The `<kbd>` elements were supposed to have been given a [makeover by Jin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126998/kbd-elements-are-still-intrusive/131447#131447) to make them less hideous. Arqade still has the old style.

Old and busted:

[image: old kbd style which overlaps the visible text]

New Hotness:

[image: new kbd style with a more streamlined appearance]

Aside from the aesthetic issues, the old key styles exceed the line-height of the text, hence the overlapping in the top image.

Comment: Those are clearly Mac keys! You can't put those on a gaming site!

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what language that keyboard was meant to type. Icelandic?

Comment: @SaintWacko just pretend it's the Surface's keyboard